# has_one through has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this `has_many` association

```
has_many :devices, through: :vehicles, foreign_key: :meid
```

I need `last_device` to be implemented as a `has_one` relation to use it with ransack gem and it can be implemented using a method like this

```
def last_device
  devices.last
end
```

I've tried a few variants but I haven't managed to get it working

```
has_one :last_device, class_name: 'Device'
```

Comment: Don't think it's possible to do that, 'cause you wouldn't have a correct setting method on that association.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've done it by splitting it into two pieces

```
has_one :last_vehicle, -> { order('vehicles.created_at DESC') }, class_name: 'Vehicle'
has_one :last_device, through: :last_vehicle, source: :device, class_name: 'Device'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible to do it the way you propose, 'cause you wouldn't have a correct setting method on that association.

The only thing I can think of (if you insist on working with ransack), is adding a `last_device_id` column to your model and then adding a relation like this:

```
has_one :last_device, class_name: Device
```

Though you'll need to update that column when a new device is added to a user's vehicle or the last one is removed.